# Time Capsule corruption problems

Tags: backup, time-machine, time-capsule

Since upgrading to High Sierra I often get a verification problem of my backups on Time Capsule. Time Machine then deletes the complete disk image (deletes all the backups) and starts with a fresh full backup.

In the log I see

```
2018-01-03 13:42:15.107627+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Starting post-backup thinning
2018-01-03 13:45:20.792460+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Deleted /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s Mac mini/2018-01-01-074807 (285 MB)
2018-01-03 13:50:10.048659+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Deleted /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s Mac mini/2018-01-01-070001 (117.7 MB)
2018-01-03 13:50:10.048669+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Post-backup thinning complete: 2 expired backups removed
2018-01-03 13:50:11.857471+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Backup completed successfully.
2018-01-03 13:50:18.592374+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Ejected Time Machine disk image: /Volumes/Data/Matteo Corti’s Mac mini.sparsebundle
2018-01-03 13:50:19.499332+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Ejected Time Machine network volume.
2018-01-03 13:50:19.507623+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Running automatic backup verification.
2018-01-03 13:50:19.512527+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Attempting to mount network destination URL: afp://Matteo%20Corti;AUTH=SRP@AirPort%20Time%20Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local./Data
2018-01-03 13:50:20.089532+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Mounted network destination at mount point: /Volumes/Data using URL: afp://Matteo%20Corti;AUTH=SRP@AirPort%20Time%20Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local./Data
2018-01-03 13:50:23.169054+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Checking for runtime corruption on /dev/disk7s2
2018-01-03 13:50:23.949260+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Verifying backup disk image.
2018-01-03 13:57:30.966843+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Backup verification failed for image /Volumes/Data/Matteo Corti’s Mac mini.sparsebundle!
2018-01-03 16:34:29.685949+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Recovery backup requested by user.
2018-01-03 17:02:25.965651+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Deleted backup image: /Volumes/Data/Matteo Corti’s Mac mini.purgeable.sparsebundle.  2.72 TB available on host volume.
2018-01-03 17:02:26.532029+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Starting manual backup
2018-01-03 17:02:27.231680+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Network destination already mounted at: /Volumes/Data
2018-01-03 17:02:27.716175+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Creating disk image /Volumes/Data/Matteo Corti’s Mac mini.sparsebundle
2018-01-03 17:03:32.758161+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Checking for runtime corruption on /dev/disk7s2
2018-01-03 17:03:36.330993+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Disk image /Volumes/Data/Matteo Corti’s Mac mini.sparsebundle mounted at: /Volumes/Time Machine Backups
2018-01-03 17:03:37.730628+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Backing up to /dev/disk7s2: /Volumes/Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb
2018-01-03 17:03:44.877270+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Starting age based thinning of Time Machine local snapshots on disk '/Volumes/External'
2018-01-03 17:03:44.896401+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Completed thinning of Time Machine local snapshots on disk '/Volumes/External' in 0.0 seconds - current free space: 1.88 TB (1,879,773,732,864 bytes), target 
free space: 25 GB (25,000,000,000 bytes), initial free space: 1.88 TB (1,879,773,732,864 bytes), urgency: 0, remaining snapshots: {(
    "com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-025617",
    "com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-011316",
    "com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-041046",
    "com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-065147",
    "com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-052939",
    "com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-082500",
    "com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-111105",
    "com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-02-180430"
)}
2018-01-03 17:03:57.396034+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Created Time Machine local snapshot with name 'com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-170356' on disk '/Volumes/External'
2018-01-03 17:03:57.401657+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Declared stable snapshot: com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-170356
2018-01-03 17:03:57.678114+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Mounted stable snapshot: com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-170356 at path: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s Mac mi
ni/2018-01-03-170356/External source: External
2018-01-03 17:03:57.820868+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Mounted reference snapshot: com.apple.TimeMachine.2018-01-03-111105 at path: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/Matteo Corti’s Mac
 mini/2018-01-03-111105/External source: External
2018-01-03 17:03:57.979861+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Initial backup of source: "Macintosh HD" (device: /dev/disk2 mount: '/' fsUUID: 440F19DC-6CB8-3A29-B132-554B14B1EF1C eventDBUUID: 6E5E4B2A-0E29-4964-8C7C-36D8
C39F2956)
2018-01-03 17:03:57.979997+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Initial backup of source: "External" (device: /dev/disk6s1 mount: '/Volumes/External' fsUUID: BC7B7429-6083-353A-85D3-ACA319870283 eventDBUUID: 10188771-A291-
4CCA-BCDB-B59ED586F5BF)
2018-01-03 17:06:03.411748+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Total content size: 755.74 GB excluded items size: 25.88 GB for volume Macintosh HD
2018-01-03 17:18:52.661500+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Total content size: 1.12 TB excluded items size: 720.34 GB for volume External
2018-01-03 17:18:52.704091+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] Found 4992292 files (1.13 TB) needing backup
2018-01-03 17:18:52.819406+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogInfo] 1.15 TB required (including padding), 2.71 TB available
2018-01-03 17:18:53.010503+0100  localhost backupd[21752]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:TMLogError] Waiting for index to be ready (100)
```

Time Machine works then well for a couple of days and then the verification fails again (image deleted followed by an initial backup).

Is anyone else experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try following the instructions here : http://jd-powered.net/notes/fixing-your-time-machine-backup

They have helped me in the past.